# Multiple Where Clauses Not Functioning

Tags: sql, ms-access

My where clause isn't working properly and i can't figure out why. I'm trying to remove any account numbers beginning with 9, and any entity codes listed below be removed from my results. It's running the query, but WITH the accounts beginning with a 9 and with the entity's listed.

```
SELECT [Emp List].ID, 
[Emp List].FirstName, 
[Emp List].LastName, 
dbo_person.prsn_crd_nbr, 
dbo_person.prsn_emp_id, 
Left([dbo_account]![account_id],8) AS Account, 
dbo_account.holder_name, 
dbo_account.entity_id
FROM (([Emp List] LEFT JOIN dbo_person ON [Emp List].emp_id = dbo_person.prsn_emp_id) 
LEFT JOIN dbo_account ON dbo_person.prsn_emp_id = dbo_account.fa_emp_id) 
LEFT JOIN dbo_account_holder ON dbo_account.account_id = dbo_account_holder.account_id
WHERE (((dbo_account.entity_id) Not Like "%7671%" 
AND (entity_id) Not Like "%851%" 
AND (entity_id) Not Like "%871%"
AND (entity_id) Not Like "%3731%" 
AND (entity_id) Not Like "%3291%") 
AND ((dbo_account_holder.account_id)<>"False") 
AND ((dbo_account.account_id) Not Like "%9%") 
AND ((dbo_account.date_account_closed) Is Null));
```

Comment: This isn't going to fix your issue, but `account_id` not beginning with `9` would be `dbo_account.account_id NOT LIKE "9%"` Putting a wildcard before the `9` insures you will get no records where there is a `9` anywhere in the `account_id`.

Comment: good to know, thank you

Comment: Perhaps it's getting too late in the day and my brain is functioning, but your logic appears sound for getting the results you are after. Is there anything left out here like an `OR` condition or some other sorcery?

Comment: The comment about wildcard preceding the "9" applies to the other number strings as well. Don't use LIKE and wildcard when you want to compare a specific string. I thought ALIKE went with % wildcard. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-wildcard-character-reference-AF00C501-7972-40EE-8889-E18ABAAD12D1